# Error while removing php package

Tags: php, linux, installation, dpkg

How can I escape from this error?

```
root@excel2012:~# sudo apt-get remove php5-imagick

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  php5-imagick

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 43 not upgraded.

7 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 426 kB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

(Reading database ... 25121 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing php5-imagick ...

sed: can't read /etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini: No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing php5-imagick (--remove):

 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2

configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-imagick

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This is probably a better question for superuser than SO.

Answer (score 1):

The file /etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini is missing.
To fix do:

1. `sudo touch /etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini`
2. `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all php5-imagick`

Answer (score 0):

Edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/php5-imagick.postrm and remove the line regarding /etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini. Then this package should be able to be removed. Remember to modify/remove /etc/php5/conf.d/imagick.ini as you wish.